# [student] --> [newbie]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

In the spirit of one day having a pure, free of meta-tags question base, i have found [student].
[student] has [69 questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/student) and is pretty much the same as [newbie] and [beginner], therefore i think it should also go the way of the dinosaurs.

Comment: Dead tags turn into fossil fuel?? Wow :) They really DID strike oil when launching SO.

Comment: @Tim Post Dead tags also eat Jeff Goldblum in box-office blockbusters

Comment: and [basic] is gaining steam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree that student is the same as newbie and beginner.

See related discussion:
[Is [homework] an exception to the no-meta-tag rule?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception/60495#60495)

It looks like [student](/questions/tagged/student) is now a synonym of [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) so this is complete.

Comment: I agree that [homework] should be kept, but why [student]?  Either the student is posting homework, which should be treated like any other form of homework, or the student is posting some other question, which should be treated like anybody else's question.  I like tags that tell me whether I should read the question and (in the case of [homework]) how to answer it.  I don't see that [student] helps me in either way.