# Do we need the "existing" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are currently [55 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/existing) on StackOverflow tagged "existing".  I don't see that this tag adds any value to these questions, or even makes much sense.  It seems to be used when the asker is asking a question about data, code, images, etc. that already 'exists' in their project, which doesn't really add anything to the discussion.

It also has no tag wiki, which is maybe an indication that no one finds it valuable/clear enough to write one?  (Not sure on this, feel free to educate me.)

So, is this tag valuable?  If not, what's the process for removing it?  Can moderators mass-delete it, or can I just go through and edit it out of the 55 questions myself?  What amount of agreement is required among the community before decisions like this can be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  It's a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  It can be safely removed from all 55 questions.

Comment: Would `homework` fall into the same category? Some people get pretty uppity about making an asker tag their question as homework. I don't see how it changes the context or how it could possibly affect the answer.

Comment: Homework is an [exception](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60495), but lately it has been [falling out of favor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123758/102937).